# codeigniter multi joins

Tags: codeigniter, join

Hello i have this join, but i wanna join another tabel named "users" and i want the "profil_billed" row, how can i do that

i mean "WHERE forum_traad.brugernavn = users.profil_billed" something like that

```
function posts($id)
{
    $this->db->select('*,forum_traad.indhold as traad_indhold,
                       forum_kommentare.indhold as kommentare_indhold,
                        forum_traad.brugernavn as traad_brugernavn,
                        forum_traad.id as traad_id
                       ');
    $this->db->from('forum_traad');
    $this->db->join('forum_kommentare', 'forum_kommentare.fk_forum_traad', 'forum_traad.id');
    $this->db->where('forum_traad.id', $id);

    $query = $this->db->get();

    if($query->num_rows > 0)
    {
        return $query->row();
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: something like that

$this->db->join('users', 'forum_traad.brugernavn', 'users.username');

Comment: but it dont work and can i have 2 joins like that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can write your query as below -

```
    $this->db->select('*,forum_traad.indhold as traad_indhold,
                       forum_kommentare.indhold as kommentare_indhold,
                        forum_traad.brugernavn as traad_brugernavn,
                        forum_traad.id as traad_id, users.profil_billed as billed
                       ');
   $this->db->from('forum_traad');
   $this->db->join('forum_kommentare', 'forum_kommentare.fk_forum_traad = forum_traad.id');
   $this->db->join('users', 'forum_traad.brugernavn = users.profil_billed');
   $this->db->where('forum_traad.id', $id);
   $query = $this->db->get();
```

For detailed documentation of the syntax i have used refer below -

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html

Comment: it dont work it go to my else in my view file that looks like this:
http://pastebin.com/45muaLLY

Comment: Are you getting an mysql error or zero rows returned? Do you need non-natural join, like a left join?

Comment: i only get this "Der blev ikke fundet nogen tråd" and that is my else, so no.. i dont know if i need left join